# Angular 4 Update list of objects in ngFor after response from http get request

Tags: angular, http, observable

I am trying to update list of objects in component. However ngFor is not aware if the array is updated. My component:

```
private lessons: Lesson[] = [];
constructor(private lessonsService: LessonsService, private http: Http) {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/Courses/').map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((response: Lesson[]) => {
      this.lessons = response;
    });
}
```

My html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let lesson of lessons|groupByLessons:'Name'; let i=index">
  <td class="ts-td-lesson">{{lesson.key}}</td>
</tr>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What makes you think ngFor is not aware the array is updated? My guess is that it's your groupBy pipe which is  incorrect. Remove it, print the JSON of each lesson inside the <td>, and you'll see that ngFor is fine. Once you've confirmed that the pipe is the problem, remove it, and group the lessons from inside the component.

Comment: I removed the pipe, but that does not help. Now the code looks like: 
            <tr *ngFor="let lesson of lessons; let i=index">
              <td class="ts-td-lesson">{{lesson.Name}}</td>
            </tr>

Comment: And, where and how do you update the array? Post a complete minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not comment yet, but may be you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` or detached change detector, or component is created in non-angular zone?

Comment: I solved this issue adding changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and marking to update component then got response from api. I used EventEmmiter to inform angular component that data was loaded. I will mark your answer as solution, because ChangeDetectionStrategy helped me.